# Dialogue does not begin with the first sentence and it starts before I press key to begin dialogue in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am working on a dialogue and questing system for a 2d game I am working on. I am attempting to have multiple NPCs that will give different quests with different dialogue that is unique to each quest. I attempt to trigger my dialogue whenever a player presses the E key. Currently my game displays the dialogue whenever the player becomes in contact with the NPCs collider. The dialogue also begins with the second sentence of the dialogue array. Additionally, once the player has interacted with multiple npcs, the dialogue for all npc becomes the dialogue of the last npc that was interacted with.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class QuestGiver :  NPC
{
    public bool AssignedQuest { get; set; }
    public bool Helped { get; set; }
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject quests;
    [SerializeField]
    private string questType;
    private Quest Quest { get; set; }


    public CharacterController2D player;

    public GameObject questWindow;
    public Text titleText;
    public Text descriptionText;
    public Text expRewardText;
    public Text currencyRewardText;

    private void Start()
    {

    }
    public override void Interact()
    {
        if (!AssignedQuest && !Helped)
        {
            DialogueManager.Instance.AddNewDialogue(dialogue, name);
            AssignQuest();
        }
        else if (AssignedQuest && !Helped)
        {
            CheckQuest();
        }
        else
        {
            DialogueManager.Instance.AddNewDialogue(Quest.completedDialogue, name);
        }
    }

    void AssignQuest()
    {
        AssignedQuest = true;
        Quest = (Quest)quests.AddComponent(Type.GetType(questType));
    }
    void CheckQuest()
    {
        if (Quest.Completed)
        {
            Quest.GiveReward();
            Helped = true;
            AssignedQuest = false;
            DialogueManager.Instance.AddNewDialogue(Quest.rewardDialogue, name);
            Destroy(quests.GetComponent(Type.GetType(questType)));
        }
        else
        {
            DialogueManager.Instance.AddNewDialogue(Quest.inProgressDialogue, name);
        }
    }

    public void OpenQuestWindow()
    {
        questWindow.SetActive(true);
        titleText.text = Quest.QuestName;
        descriptionText.text = Quest.Description;
        expRewardText.text = Quest.ExpRewards.ToString();
        currencyRewardText.text = Quest.CurrencyReward.ToString();
    }

    public void AcceptQuest()
    {
        questWindow.SetActive(false);
        Quest.Completed = false;
        player.questsList.Add(Quest);
    }
}
```

This is the Quest script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;

[System.Serializable]
public class Quest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<QuestGoal> Goals { get; set; } = new List<QuestGoal>();

    public string[] inProgressDialogue, rewardDialogue, completedDialogue;

    public string QuestName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int ExpRewards { get; set; }
    public int CurrencyReward { get; set; }
    public Item ItemReward { get; set; }
    public bool Completed { get; set; }

    public void CheckGoals()
    {
        Completed = Goals.All(q => q.Completed);
        if (Completed) GiveReward();
        
    }
    public void GiveReward()
    {
        if (ItemReward != null)
                    Inventory.inventory.Add(ItemReward);
        
    }
```

This is the NPC:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NPC : Interactable
{
    public string[] dialogue;
    public string name;

    public override void Interact()
    {  
        base.Interact();
        DialogueManager.Instance.AddNewDialogue(dialogue, name);
        Debug.Log("Interacting with " + name);
    }

    public void TriggerDialogue()
    {
        FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().AddNewDialogue(dialogue, name);
    }
}
```

This is my dialogue script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class DialogueManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    #region

    public static DialogueManager Instance { get; set; }
    public GameObject dialoguePanel;
    private void Awake()
    {
        dialoguePanel.SetActive(false);
        if (Instance != null && Instance != this)
        {
            Debug.Log(Instance);
            Destroy(Instance);
        }
        else
        {
            Instance = this;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public Text nameText, dialogueText;
    public Button continueButton;

    public Animator animator;
    public string npcName;
    int dialogueIndex;
    public List<string> dialogueLines = new List<string>();

    void Start()
    {
    }

    public void AddNewDialogue(string[] lines, string npcName)
    {
        dialogueIndex = 0;
        dialogueLines = new List<string>();
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            dialogueLines.Add(line);
        }
        this.npcName = npcName;

        Debug.Log(dialogueLines.Count);
        Debug.Log(npcName);

        CreateDialogue();
    }

    public void CreateDialogue()
    {
        nameText.text = npcName;
        dialogueText.text = dialogueLines[dialogueIndex];
        dialoguePanel.SetActive(true);
        animator.SetBool("IsOpen", true);

        ContinueDialogue();
    }


    public void ContinueDialogue()
    {
        if (dialogueIndex < dialogueLines.Count - 1)
        {
            dialogueIndex++;
            dialogueText.text = dialogueLines[dialogueIndex];
        }
        else
        {
            EndDialogue();
        }

        StopAllCoroutines();
        StartCoroutine(TypeSentence(dialogueText.text));
    }

    IEnumerator TypeSentence (string sentence)
    {
        dialogueText.text = "";
        foreach (char letter in sentence.ToCharArray())
        {
            dialogueText.text += letter;
            yield return null;
        }
    }


    void EndDialogue()
    {
        animator.SetBool("IsOpen", false);
        Debug.Log("End of conversation");
    }
}
```

This is part of the Player controller:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using Spine.Unity;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class CharacterController2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject triggeringNpc;
    public GameObject npcText;

    public List<Quest> questsList = new List<Quest>();

    private bool triggering;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Interactable interactable = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Interactable>();

        if (interactable != null)
        {
            interactable.Interact();

        }
        if (other.tag == "NPC")
        {
            triggering = true;
            triggeringNpc = other.gameObject;
            
        }
        if (other.tag == "QuestGiver")
        {
            triggering = true;
            triggeringNpc = other.gameObject;
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "NPC")
        {
            triggering = false;
            triggeringNpc = null;
        }
        if (other.tag == "QuestGiver")
        {
            triggering = false;
            triggeringNpc = null;
        }
    }
        private void Update()
    {
        if (triggering)
        {
            npcText.SetActive(true);
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
            {
                FindObjectOfType<QuestGiver>().TriggerDialogue();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            npcText.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance, sorry for the long post.

Comment: Where/How are you calling Interact()?

Comment: I am calling the Interact() from my player controller by using OnTriggerEnter2d @ThomasFinch

Comment: @ThomasFinch I added the playerController to the Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Dialogue starting on the second line:**

In the CreateDialogue() method, at the end you are calling ContinueDialogue(). So you create dialogue and then immediately tell it to go to the next line. I think instead you might want to be calling StartCoroutine(TypeSentence(dialogueText.text)) at the end of CreateDialogue().

---

**Interaction issues:**

You're calling Interact() at the beginning of OnTriggerEnter2D by doing interactable.Interact(). Here, erase all the code inside your OnTriggerEnter2D method and replace it with this.

```
if (other.tag == "NPC" || other.tag == "QuestGiver") {
    triggering = true;
    triggeringNpc = other.gameObject;
} else if (interactable != null) { interactable.Interact(); }
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue of the dialogue starting on the second sentence. I still need to work on the interaction issue but this helps a lot.

Comment: Updated my answer with the exact solution for the interaction issues.

Comment: This is perfect for one npc, works like a charm. However when I try and add the second npc, I have the same issue I was having initially in which the dialogue for both becomes the same one.